# Form Text Input Alignment Issue

Tags: forms, input

I looked at the other forms on here and I still can't seem to get anywhere for whatever reason. I've tried several different methods that I've found on here and nothing is working >.< Can someone help me align these text boxes? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```html
<h1>Registration</h1>
<div class="containter">
  <form name=registration>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="">
    <br><br> Password: <input type="text" name="password" value="">
    <br><br> First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" value="">
    <br><br> Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" value="">
    <br><br> Date of Birth: <input type="text" name="bDay" value="">
    <br><br> Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="">
    <br><br> Phone Number: <input type="text" name="firstName" value="">
    <br><br>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put it in a table:

```html
<body>
    <h1>Registration</h1>
    <div class="containter">
      <form name=registration>
        <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="username" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password: </td><td><input type="text" name="password" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>First Name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="firstName" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Last Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="lastName" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Date of Birth: </td><td><input type="text" name="bDay" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Email: </td><td><input type="text" name="email" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Phone Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="firstName" value=""></td> 
        </tr>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/) and this is what you could get. Checkout this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ijkk/pen/JjdvxjE)

Bootstrap is used by a lot of companies and is an easier way to create responsive forms

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Registration</h1>
  <form name=registration>
    <div class="containter">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-labe">Username:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-labe">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="password" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-labe">First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstName" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-labe">Last Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastName" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-labe">Date of Birth:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="date" name="bDay" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-labe">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-labe">Phone Number:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstName" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```